# Element is not clickable at point in protractor using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, protractor

Below is my code which I've tried to avoid the error but it doesn't clicks the element or throws any more errors. Please help in correcting the code.

```
async testMethod() {
    let button = element( by.cssContainingText('span.mat-button-wrapper','abc'));
    await browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(button), this.DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME_SECONDS * 1000, 'failed to click the button!');
    button.getText().then((text)=>{
        console.log('Get the text of the ele: ' + text.toUpperCase());
         expect(text.toUpperCase()).toEqual(expectedValue);
    });

    await browser.manage().window().setSize(1000, 1000);
    await browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)').then(()=>{
         browser.actions().mouseMove(button).perform();
        browser.sleep(10000);
    });

    /* await browser.executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible';",
       "arguments[0].style.display = 'block';",
       "arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",
       button.getWebElement());
    */
       browser.actions().mouseMove(button).perform();
       browser.sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: It likely doesn't click the element because at no point during your test is the code to click. Somewhere you should have `button.click()`

Comment: Fantastic, it has worked! Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the working code if anybody needs it. Share if there is a better implementation of it

```
async testMethod() {
    let button = element( by.cssContainingText('span.mat-button-wrapper','abc'));
    await browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(button), this.DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME_SECONDS * 1000, 'failed to click the button!');
    button.getText().then((text)=>{
        console.log('Get the text of the ele: ' + text.toUpperCase());
         expect(text.toUpperCase()).toEqual(expectedValue);
    });
         await browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)').then(()=>{
            browser.sleep(2000);
    });

        button.click();
}
```